# Change resolution(screen size) on Android ICS virtualbox issue

Tags: android, linux, android-emulator, virtualbox

I have built android ICS(4.0.3) for virtualBox. And it runs well with default resolution 800x600. 
However, when I change the virtualbox resolution to non-default ones, say 1280x800.
Then I get error "Unfornately, System UI has stopped". And the system hangs there. In addition, I cannot even connect to this device to see the logs when resolution changes.

Would you please give me some help? Thanks.

BTW,
The way I change resolution is suggested by [Buildroid](http://www.buildroid.org/blog/?p=107) ----

First  add a “custom video mode” to .vbox configuration file : Add the line 
< ExtraDataItem name=”CustomVideoMode1″ value=”1280x800x16″/> 
just after the already present “ExtraDataItem” entries.
Modify the linux kernel options to replace the existing vga=xxx by a vga=ask
Then, choose the expected resolution.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you find solution in this wiki article: [Android Emulation](http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/Android_emulation).